# Find the minimum distance between a line and a parabola

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, analytic-geometry, maxima-minima

Find the minimum distance between the line $y = 4x + 4$ and the parabola 
$x=y^2$.

Not sure how to solve this problem?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: the segment connecting the closest points on the line and parabola must intersect the line at a $90^{\circ}$ angle. Otherwise, we could simply draw a line segment at a $90^{\circ}$ angle to the line that intersects the parabola in the same place, and our previous segment is the hypotenuse of a right triangle, one of whose legs is the new segment (which is then necessarily shorter than the hypotenuse).

Comment: Hint: Consider the function $f(a,b)=\|(a,4a+4)-(b^2,b)\|_2^2$. The square root of the minimum of $f$ is the minimal distance.

Comment: Alternatively, parametrize the parabola as $(t,t^2)$ and minimize over all $(x,t)$ the (squared) distance between $(x,4x+4)$ and $(t,t^2)$ -- so minimize (x-t)^2+(4x+4-t^2)^2$. Edit: Mundron wrote as I was finishing this up! Same idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the distance between the tangent line $yy_1=p(x+x_1)$ to the parabola $y^2=x$ and $y=4x+4$, which parallel to the tangent line.

Since $p=\frac{1}{2}$, we obtain $\frac{1}{2y_1}=4$, which gives $y_1=\frac{1}{8}$ and $\left(\frac{1}{64},\frac{1}{8}\right)$ is a touching point.

Id est, for the distance we obtain:
$$\frac{\left|4\cdot\frac{1}{64}-\frac{1}{8}+4\right|}{\sqrt{4^2+(-1)^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The minimum distance is at the $x$ at which the tangent to the parabola is $4$. Where the tangent is parallel to the straight line:

[image]

So, one has to solve the following equation

$$\frac12x^{-\frac12}=4.$$

The solution is $$x_m=\frac1{64}.$$